# DisplayPort 1.4 to HDMI 2.0

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, displayport

I'm trying to connect my computer (using DisplayPort) to three displays (using HDMI) and I want to achieve 4K@60Hz for each display.

### Graphics Card

- [PNY NVidia GeForce GTX 1080 Ti Blower Edition](https://www.pny.com/previous-generation-geforce/id-156/geforce_gtx_1080_ti_blower_edition)
- 3x DisplayPort 1.4
- 1x HDMI 2.0

### Display(s)

- [LG 27UD68P Ultra HD 4K 60Hz IPS Monitor](https://www.lg.com/uk/monitors/lg-27UD68P)
- 1x DisplayPort 1.2
- 2x HDMI 2.0

### What I have tried

- Passive DisplayPort to HDMI cable works but only 4K@30Hz.
- Active DisplayPort to HDMI cable didn't work at all.
- HDMI to HDMI works at 4K@60Hz as expected with HDMI DeepColor turned ON.
- DisplayPort to DisplayPort works and I can run 3x 4K@60Hz.

### Questions & Answers

> If the graphics card has 3x DisplayPort and the monitor(s) have 1x DisplayPort (each), then why don't you connect the computer to the monitor(s) using DisplayPort to DisplayPort?

Because the DisplayPort on each monitor is already in use by another machine.

> Why don't you use HDMI for the other machine and DisplayPort for *this* machine?

The other machine is a Mac Pro (2013 "TrashCan") with 6x Mini-DisplayPort/Thunderbolt and 1x HDMI 2.0. Connecting the machine via Mini-DisplayPort/Thunderbolt to HDMI only allows an equivalent conversion of HDMI 1.4, so again it results in 4K@30Hz.

### Question

What options do I have (if any) to get this working so that both machines can support running 3x 4K@60Hz displays?

### Notes

As per Tom Yan's question, I have tried using the following active DisplayPort to HDMI cable: https://www.amazon.co.uk/UGREEN-Displayport-Eyefinity-Multi-Screen-Technology/dp/B078M18G5F

Comment: `Active DisplayPort to HDMI cable didn't work at all.` I guess you want to figure out why. Any chance that what you tried is an active HDMI to DisplayPort cable?

Comment: Sounds like you are hitting a bandwidth limit. 3x 4K is 12K, that is a hell of a lot of bandwidth. @30Hz is half the bandwidth. If HDMI supports it, you definitely need a really good cable that supports it.

Comment: @TomYan take a look at my edit (notes at the bottom including a link to the cable I tried)

Comment: That looks fine. You may want to at least return it and get another one (perhaps from a different vendor) in case it is broken or has some corner-case compatibility issue with the monitor? (Also search a bit about the monitor model and see if anyone report similar issue that can perhaps be worked around by adjusting an OSC setting.)